# Can anyone suggests online console to practice big data program

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, bigdata

I want to practice big data . I can't install it into my laptop cause it's my office laptop. Can anyone suggests me any online console to perform big data program . please help I'm new to this don't know anything .

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow* - See [help]

Comment: Note: You already tagged AWS, and AWS has EMR training and certifcations, so start with that